# Validate SDK user is my client or not?

Tags: android, sdk

I developed one SDK for my clients.I want to give SDK access only my clients.I will give token for my client.How can i validate that client is my client or not? Someone steals the my client authenticate details or my clients give to others use their credential to access my SDK.I want to find the fraud who use my SDK illegally.How can I validate it?

Comment: Sounds like you need two factor authentication. https://www.google.com/search?q=android+two+factor+authentication

Comment: I think this is not suitable for SDK client validation.

Comment: By client do you mean customer or app?

Comment: for example one app taken my sdk and i will give sdk and access token to that app.That app is given access token(my sdk access token) to some other apps.Other apps also used my sdk.so i want to find that fraud.sorry for my bad english.if your not get my question please ask me @nasch

Comment: Yeah I get it.  The only thing I can think of is to make the user of your app buy a $.099 subscription to your service (SDK) from the play store.  Then the app has to send the subscription purchase data to the server, and the server can validate the purchase.  I think it can check to make sure the purchase was made from your app as well but I'm not totally certain on that.  Otherwise I can't think how you can verify that it is your app making the call.

Comment: Why can't you use the application package name which is unique to check / validate the uniqueness of the SDK usage in apps ? It means if you gave a token to one app, map the token with the app package name and if any other app is trying to access , then check it and block it

Comment: if others also used same package name but that app is not in play store we cannot validate(as per my knowledge but i am not sure). @KingofMasses

Comment: I understood, In this case you don't ask the app guys to send the package name, instead of it , you took it from SDK and store it. and don't allow them to change it or modify it from SDK.. Since app is not in the play store it is difficult to put such a validation to verify the fraud

Comment: thank you @KingofMasses,but facebook is detecting the same thing .how the facebook is done any idea?